# Java Updatable Resultset Anomaly with UTF-8 data in English Windows

Tags: java, mysql, unicode, utf-8, resultset

I am facing a weird problem. I am getting exception when I try to update or delete row in updatable resultset which contains non-english utf-characters. However insert goes fine.

---

java.sql.SQLException: refreshRow() called on row that has been deleted or had primary key changed.

---

The weirdest things are:

1. This error happens only when compiled jar is run in windows
2. However same jar run in Linux runs fine for same data without problem.
3. Same project run from within IDE runs also fine in Windows.

Other information in case that will be helpful

---

OS: Windows XP (English with non-english language support installed)

DB: MySQL, encoding utf8, collation - utf8_general_ci

IDE: Netbeans 6.9.1

JDK: 6 update 23

Connector/J 5.1.15 (Just switch to check if this works but same problem with version 14 too)

Connection string includes: "useUnicode=true" and "characterEncoding=utf8"

Initially thought that IDE has something to do so posted this message in netbeans forum

http://forums.netbeans.org/topic36558.html

Also cross posted in mysql JDBC forums hoping to find some answer

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,408795,408795

but couldn't get any help there.

---

So far, the problem seems to be Windows. May be this is just minor issue but can't think of any work around.

Need some suggestion

Thanks and regards

Deepak

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your IDE is override the default encoding that you get when you run your application from the command line. If you check the actual JVM arguments the IDE uses (normally available in the output window of your IDE), you will probably see the inclusion of a file-encoding argument, like this:

```
-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"
```

Try to start your application with this JVM argument and see if it makes any difference, and if not - compare the actual encoding used when run from the IDE and on the command line like this:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("file.encoding"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it. I don't understand why this is happenning but this is caused when your primary key of mysql table is combined. In my database there are many tables that have combined primary key and others that have auto-increment. Likely i noticed that this problem didn't occur in tables with auto-increment primary key.